# RoboForm Desktop v7.9.17.5 Trial Period

Tags: roboform

I'd been running an older version of RoboForm (6.x I think) for several years. Last week I had a devastating hard drive crash ..new hard drive, reinstalling programs ..you know the drill. I installed the latest RF Desktop version only to find out it's no longer free beyond 10 logins.

My question: Will I still be able to run and edit RoboForm Editor without having to purchase a license or will the RoboForm Desktop Editor stop functioning on the last trial day? I understand that auto-fill / auto login features won't function but I can get by with them. I just need to be able to store and edit my passwords and logins locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
~Thanks~

Comment: Yes, usually trial versions stop working after trial period  has ended. What is link to software?

Comment: So you don't have the v6 installer and license key? Or was it lost in the crash?

Comment: Though I have not used this site, http://www.oldversion.com/windows/roboform/ has older versions. Of course, check any downloaded software for malware, e.g. at VirusTotal.

Comment: Lastpass is free and more secure, upgrade to premium for $12 a year...https://lastpass.com/features/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick replies.
Moab - Yes, usually they do but I've been using v6 for several years without having to license it. The auto-fill and auto-login features no longer worked but the editor did. So I was just wondering if that would still be the case with the latest version.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik - Thank you for that link. I'll check it out and will be sure to use VirusTotal if I decide ro reinstall the older version. I've learned my lesson the hard way with with Malware. Download.com is the worst.

Answer (score 0):

**FREE LICENSE OPTIONS:**

1) If you search online, you can get a free Roboform license if you sign up for one month of Netflix.

2) There is also a special license for students who can verify e-mail from a .edu that is also free as long as you can verify your .edu e-mail each year.